# ASP MVC Filters, where implement interface or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filter, action-filter

Just wondering, googling around how to use filters in asp mvc 4. I have found some people defines them like this:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
```

And some like this:

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
```

ActionFilterAttribute already has all operations to override, why should i implement the interface as well?

Also for example in the next code, at the end the filter is called again, why is this?

```
public class 

CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)


    {
        // TODO: Add your acction filter's tasks here

        // Log Action Filter Call
        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

        ActionLog log = new ActionLog()
        {
            Controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName,
            Action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName + " (Logged By: Custom 

Action Filter)",
            IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
            DateTime = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp
        };

        storeDB.ActionLogs.Add(log);
        storeDB.SaveChanges();

        this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [MSDN definition of ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)  you will see that it is an abstract class that inherits interfaces *IActionFilter* AND *IResultFilter*.

In effect inheriting from *ActionFilterAttribute*,

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
```

is equivalent to inheriting class  *FilterAttribute* and interfaces *IActionFilter* and *IResultFilter*

```
public class CustomFilter : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
```

and is no different than

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter, IResultFilter
```

So inheriting from *ActionFilterAttribute* is no different than inheriting from *ActionFilterAttribute* and *IActionFilter*.

Comment: But seems redudant, isnt it? So inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute would be enough?

Comment: @user1777914, **totally redundant**. Yes ActionFilterAttribute is the total package.